# Android Studio "The value null assigned to MediaPlayer is never used"

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem in Android Studio. I am making a sound board and I want to make my MediaPlayer null when it has finished playing. I have created an on complete listener but inside the listener when I make my MediaPlayer equal to null, the studio states a warning that "The value null assigned to "mp" is never used."

```
public void playUpToUs (View view) {
    if (mp == null){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.its_up_to_us);
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
                mp = null;
            }
        });

    } else {
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
    }
}
```

I also have four other methods just like this except that they play a different sound on click. I am probably making an obvious mistake but I would really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Is playUpToUs() spelled correctly inside your XML? :)

Comment: Yes it is. My question has been answered. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `mp` parameter in the `onCompletion` method is shadowing the `mp` member variable that you're trying to modify.  You're actually setting the parameter to null, which is useless here.  You want to modify the shadowed instance instead.

Either use a different variable name that doesn't conflict with the member variable, or refer to the member using the outer class name as a qualifier (such as `MyActivity.this.mp`, if your the outer class is MyActivity).